# Does clang have function attribute: unroll loop like gcc?

Tags: clang, llvm

Like title, I know clang have statement attribute `#pragma clang loop unroll(enable)`

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#extensions-for-loop-hint-optimizations ,

gcc's like

```
__attribute__((optimize("unroll-loops")))
```

but not found function leval attribute in clang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Primary clang loop hints?  No.

The primary way Clang accepts loop hints is via the
[`#pragma clang loop`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#pragma-clang-loop)
family, and these do not have attribute equivalents (as of Clang 16).
The linked documentation has a table of "Supported Syntaxes", which is
a multi-column table, and the only populated column is the one for the
pragmas.

This can also be observed in the source code, at
[Attr.td:3654](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-16.0.6/clang/include/clang/Basic/Attr.td#L3654),
for which the only "spellings" are the pragma ones:

```
  let Spellings = [Pragma<"clang", "loop">, Pragma<"", "unroll">,
                   Pragma<"", "nounroll">, Pragma<"", "unroll_and_jam">,
                   Pragma<"", "nounroll_and_jam">];
```

### OpenCL loop hints?  Yes.

Clang also accepts the
[`opencl_unroll_hint`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#pragma-clang-loop)
attribute.  Its meaning is documented in
[OpenCL C 2.0 Specification document](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/specs/2.2/pdf/OpenCL_C.pdf):

> 6.11.5. Specifying Attribute For Unrolling Loops
>
> The `__attribute__((opencl_unroll_hint))` and
> `__attribute__((opencl_unroll_hint(n)))` attribute qualifiers can be
> used to specify that a loop (for, while and do loops) can be unrolled.
> This attribute qualifier can be used to specify full unrolling or
> partial unrolling by a specified amount. This is a compiler hint and the
> compiler may ignore this directive.
>
> n is the loop unrolling factor and must be a positive integral compile
> time constant expression. An unroll factor of 1 disables unrolling. If n
> is not specified, the compiler determines the unrolling factor for the
> loop.

Despite having "OpenCL" in the name, it works generally.  For example,
the loop in this function:

```
void my_strcpy(char *d, char const *s)
{
    __attribute__((opencl_unroll_hint(4)))
    while (*s != 0) {
        *(d++) = *(s++);
    }
    *d = 0;
}
```

will be unrolled by Clang-16 four times with `-O2` when targeting x86_64
[(godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/cEaM8b78K).

These hints are not as capable as the primary clang loop hints available
via `#pragma`, but may suffice, depending on the intended use.